# How do I decode whether a network packet is SSH or not using python and the library Scapy

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, scapy

I am using Python 3.7 and the Scapy library and I am unable to detect if a TCP packet is SSH or not.

I have tried to find an example, but have not found one that shows how to do this.

```
from scapy.all import *

self.__Pkts = rdpcap("sample.pcap")
pkt = self.__Pkts[i]
if pkt.haslayer('IP'):
    self.__NumIpPkts += 1
has_ssh = self.__Pkts[i]['IP'].getlayer('TCP').getlayer('SSH')
if pkt.haslayer('TCP') or has_ssh:
   self.__NumTcpPkts += 1
```

The code presented is able to detect IP and TCP packets, but it cannot detect SSH packets.  I want to detect SSH packets.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Scapy does not come with a SSH layer implementation out of the box. What you can easily do is check whether the TCP packet is using port 22 and then in those cases assume it is an SSH packet and store the raw layer data.

If you want to do a more elaborate check you will have to implement your own scapy layer or find one on the internet: https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssh/blob/master/src/scapy/layers/ssh.py

I have not tested the implementation provided in the link and I would suggest using it merely as a template for your own implementation while also following https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html